# Is there a way to pull out two successive records only if they occur one after the other in a series of files?

Tags: awk, bioinformatics

I'm trying to pull out two successive records, but only if those records occur one after the other. I'm working with files that look like this:

```
#File1
>CHB001 PatternA
RANDOMSTRINGOFLETTERS
LETTERSRANDOMSTRINGHH
>CHB002 PatternB
RANDOMSTRINGOFLETTERS
LETTERSRANDOMSTRINGHH
LETTERSRANDOMSTRINGHH
>CHB002 PatternC
RANDOMSTRINGOFLETTERS
LETTERSRANDOMSTRINGHH

#File2
>CHB0022 PatternA
RANDOMSTRINGOFLETTERS
LETTERSRANDOMSTRINGHH
>CHB0023 PatternC
RANDOMSTRINGOFLETTERS
LETTERSRANDOMSTRINGHH
>CHB0024 PatternB
RANDOMSTRINGOFLETTERS
LETTERSRANDOMSTRINGHH
LETTERSRANDOMSTRINGHH
```

I want to pull out everything under PatternA and PatternB from all files, but only if they occur one after the other. My desired output is:

```
>CHB001 PatternA
RANDOMSTRINGOFLETTERS
LETTERSRANDOMSTRINGHH
>CHB002 PatternB
RANDOMSTRINGOFLETTERS
LETTERSRANDOMSTRINGHH
LETTERSRANDOMSTRINGHH
```

I've tried:

```
awk -v RS='>' -v ORS='>' '/PatternA/,/PatternB/' file*.txt > output.txt
```

But this would include PatternC from file 2 in the output and I want to skip file2 because PatternA and PatternB don't occur successively. Next I tried this command:

```
awk -v RS='>' -v ORS='>' '/PatternA/{l=NR}/PatternB/&&NR==l+1' file*.txt > output.txt
```

This prints out this:

```
>CHB002 PatternB
RANDOMSTRINGOFLETTERS
LETTERSRANDOMSTRINGHH
LETTERSRANDOMSTRINGHH
```

This gets me closer as I only print PatternB from file1.txt (which I do want to include in my output) and I exclude PatternB from file2.txt, which I don't want. However, I also want to include PatternA with PatternB in my desired output. The CHB### pattern is variable and can't rely upon that. I feel like this should be something I can accomplish in a one line command without needing to write a script, but I'm stuck (also new to this).

Comment: Are those fasta files?

Comment: yeah they're fasta files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never use range expressions (`/start/,/end/`) as while they make the code for trivial tasks very slightly briefer, they need a complete rewrite and duplicate conditions for the tiniest change in requirements. Also never use a variable named `l` as it looks far too much like the number `1` and so obfuscates your code. Finally - creating a one-line command should never be a goal of writing software as it suggests you favor brevity over everything that actually matters in good software such as tight cohesion, loose coupling, efficiency, portability, clarity, simplicity, and robustness.

```
$ cat tst.awk
/^>/ {
    prt()
    prevBuf = currBuf
    prevKey = currKey
    currBuf = ""
    currKey = $2
}
{ currBuf = currBuf $0 ORS }
END { prt() }

function prt() {
    if ( ( currKey == "PatternB" ) && ( prevKey == "PatternA" ) ) {
        printf "%s%s", prevBuf, currBuf
    }
}
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file1
>CHB001 PatternA
RANDOMSTRINGOFLETTERS
LETTERSRANDOMSTRINGHH
>CHB002 PatternB
RANDOMSTRINGOFLETTERS
LETTERSRANDOMSTRINGHH
LETTERSRANDOMSTRINGHH

$ awk -f tst.awk file2
$
```

Answer (score 0):

with multi-char `RS`

```
$ awk -v RS='(^|\n)>' '$2~/PatternA/{a=1; p=$0; next} 
                       a{if($2~/PatternB/) print RT p RT $0; a=0}' file1

>CHB001 PatternA
RANDOMSTRINGOFLETTERS
LETTERSRANDOMSTRINGHH
>CHB002 PatternB
RANDOMSTRINGOFLETTERS
LETTERSRANDOMSTRINGHH
LETTERSRANDOMSTRINGHH
```

has an extra newline at the top, easy to get rid if you change `print RT p RT $0` to `print ">" p "\n>" $0`.  But perhaps not important.

Or, with other `awk`s if `>` is not appearing anywhere else

```
$ awk -v RS='>' '$2~/PatternA/{a=1; p=$0; next} 
                 a{if($2~/PatternB/) print RT p RT $0; a=0}' file
```